# How do I disable "cordova-plugin-local-notifications" notifications after closing an app created with Cordova?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, localnotification

- iOS *14.0*
- cordova-plugin-local-notifications *0.9.0-beta.2*

Hello. Sorry for the poor translation.

I am developing an application using Cordova and am using the
"cordova-plugin-local-notifications" plugin to implement local notifications.

Currently, I am outputting local notifications 10 seconds after the application is moved to the background,
and I have written the following

---

```
  cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: "Test",
    text: "Test Message.",
    trigger: {unit:"second", in:10}
  });
```

---

If we implement this process, local notifications will be output even after the application is closed.

How can I prevent local notifications from being output after the application is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the pending notifications when the user closes the app, try

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
      cordova.plugins.notification.local.clear();
 });
```

I'm not certain it's `clear` or `clearAll`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
After trying, it seems that the `beforeunload` and `unload` events are not working when the application is closed....
Therefore, we could not stop the notifications.